# Is there a bijective continuous map from $[0,\infty)$ to $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Is there a bijective continuous map from $[0,\infty)$ to $\mathbb{R}$?

Whether such a function exists or not, I am trying to prove. The converse is false, that is , there is no continuous bijection from $\mathbb{R}$ to $[0,\infty)$

Comment: This is more or less the same question as this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8149/points-of-discontinuity-of-a-bijective-function-f-mathbbr-to-0-infty?rq=1  see if it helps

Comment: An injective continuous map on an interval of $\mathbb R$ is either increasing everywhere or decreasing everywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A different route.

Suppose $f : [0,\infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

Either $\forall x > 0 : f(x) > f(0)$ or $\forall x > 0 : f(x) < f(0)$.

If not then $\exists x, y > 0: f(x) > f(0) \land f(y) < f(0)$.  The intermediate value theorem now says that there is a value $z$ between $x$ and $y$ with $f(z) = f(0)$ contradicting bijectivity.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** $[0,\infty)\setminus\{0\}$ is connected, whereas $\Bbb R\setminus\{f(0)\}$ isn't.