# Every bijection $f:\Bbb{R}\rightarrow[0,\infty)$ has infinitely many points of discontinuity.

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers, continuity

> **Question:** Every bijection $f:\Bbb{R}\rightarrow[0,\infty)$ has infinitely many points of discontinuity.

Comment: You may refer this - https://math.stackexchange.com/q/8149/802621

Answer (score 1):

The following is a topological insight. I will show there is at least one discontinuity.

If possible let $f:\Bbb R\to [0,\infty)$ be a bijective continuous function. Then, one can show $\lim_{x\to \pm \infty}f(x)=\infty$. In other words, we can extend the map $f$ to a map $\widetilde f:\Bbb S^1\to [0,\infty]$. Note that $\Bbb S^1$ is the one point compactification of $\Bbb R$ and $[0,\infty]\simeq [0,1]$ is one point compactification of $[0,\infty)$. Also, $\widetilde f$ is bijective, hence a homeomorphism. But we know, $\Bbb S^1$ is not homeomorphic to $[0,1]$.

Comment: Homomorphism needs the inverse map to be continuous.

Comment: From  a compact  space to a Hausdorff space a bijective map is always is homeomorphism.

Comment: Yes, true. Thanks

Comment: This is a nice answer so +1!