# Is there a way to map $[0, \infty[ $ onto $]- \infty, \infty[$ and vice versa?

Tags: real-analysis, functions

As the title says. I'm actually writing a program and a part of it has to do these mappings. I just wish to do something like 2 functions `f(x)` and `g(x)`, where the first maps $[0, \infty[ $ to $[- \infty, \infty]$ and `g(x)` does the opposite, preferably in an uncomplicated way. It does not have to be continuous.

Comment: There is a  map from any set to any other set. :-)

Comment: A bijective function $g$ from  $\Bbb R$ to $[0, \infty)$ has *infinitely many* discontinuities, compare https://math.stackexchange.com/q/8149.

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy: $[\cdots]$ *to any other set* --- except when the first set is empty and the second set is not empty? (I'm not sure whether the empty function qualifies as a map from the empty set to a nonempty set -- I'd need to look at a standard set theory text for precise definitions for something like this.)

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro I think that one does qualify, but there are no maps from non-empty sets to the empty set.

Comment: So what is it in this case @KaviRamaMurthy ?

Comment: Why is my question downvoted?

Comment: Do you know the Mathematical definition of a function from one set to another? This  questioin is simply absurd in the present form so I have downvoted it.

Comment: Instead of correcting it? Or explaining what's wrong? That's not really nice of you...

Comment: *Or explaining what's wrong?* --- Kavi's first comment does this. Your question is like asking if a living person has a head. Possibly you meant "**onto** $[- \infty, \infty]$" instead of "**to** $[- \infty, \infty]$" (i.e. you want every element in the target set to "be used"). (BTW, I didn't downvote.)

Comment: Well, YOUR comment makes things clear and now I know how I should edit my question. Kavi's doesn't help a bit in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

Take
$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
\ln(x) & \text{if } x \in (0,+\infty)\\
0 & x = 0
\end{cases}.$$

Comment: not a map $f(1)=f(0)$ but the idea of logarithm is fine.

Comment: why can we have $f(1) = f(0)$?

Comment: From where comes your definition of map ? A map is not just a synonym of function ?

Comment: @zwim map = function and it need not be bijective...

Comment: Ok, but the question strongly suggest this should be the case, you need to anticipate OP desires :-)

Comment: Calculator says `ln(-5) = nan`

Answer (score 0):

There should be plenty of ways, but here's mine:
Given a number $x$ write this value as $n + q$ where $n$ is the integer part. Then define $ f(n+q) = -n -2q$ for $q \in (0,0.5]$ and f(n + q) = n + 2q for $n\in (0.5,1]$. Just make sure that if say you had $f(6)$ this needs to be written as $f(5 + 1)$. It's quite easy from this to work out your other function $g$, and also the inverses of these functions.

Answer (score 0):

I propose $f(x)=\begin{cases}\frac x{x-1}&x\in[0,\infty)\setminus\{1\}\\1& x=1\end{cases}$ for $f:[0,+\infty)\to\mathbb R$

Unfortunately for the other direction, this is not as simple as Martin R's comment pointed out.

We have to proceed in two steps $\mathbb R\overset{g_1}{\mapsto}(0,+\infty)\overset{g_2}{\mapsto}[0,+\infty)$

For instance $g_1(x)=e^x$ and $g_2(x)=\begin{cases}x-1&x\in\mathbb N\\x& \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$

Note: *we do not have $f^{-1}=g_2\circ g_1$, but if you need a proper reciprocal, you can proceed the same way with $f_1(x)=\ln(x)$, can you see what $f_2$ should be in this case.*

Answer (score -2):

Speaking of digital programming, there is a maximum and minimum in any signed or unsigned data type. Some data types support the representation of infinity, but not all of them.
It is practical to think of a linear mapping such as $f:[0,M) \rightarrow (m,M)$ defined by
$$f(x) =  \frac{M - m}{M}x + m$$
where $m$ and $M$ is the smallest and the largest number the data type can represent. It has good properties to handle; linear, continuous, and bijective. Furthermore, it is efficient in the sense of computational overhead.

Comment: There is something not quite right. Take `-5` and 8 bits as maximum storage as example: `f(-5)=((128--127)/128)*(-5)+(-127) = -137`.

Comment: @topkek For integer type data, you should not write that equation directly. I suggest `(int8_t)((M - m)*x/M + m)`. Meanwhile, your example is not a counterexample because -5 is not an element in the domain. Note that standard integer ranges from -128 to 127.

Comment: Oh sorry, I thought you meant the other way around *facepalm*