# Discontinuities of bijection $ f : \mathbb{R} \to [0,\infty) $ has infinitely many points of discontinuity

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

This question was asked in my Mid term exam held last week and I was unable to solve it. So, I am looking for some help here.

> Show that every bijection $f : \mathbb{R} \to [0,\infty)$ has infinite many points of discontinuity.

I am at loss of ideas. There are some results in the functions of bounded variation like (If f is monotonic on [a,b] , then the set of discontinuities of f is countable) but none of them could be used here.

I thought of letting that $f: \mathbb{R} \to[0 ,\infty$) has only finite many points of disconuity but was unable to think how should I proceed for  any contradiction.

Can you outline a argument?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/8149/943723