# Let $f: \Bbb R\to [0,\infty)$ be bijective, show that $f$ has infinite many discontinuities.

Tags: continuity

> Let $f: \Bbb R\to [0,\infty)$ be bijective, show that $f$ has infinite many discontinuities.

Clearly, there exists one and only one $x_0$ such that $f(x_0)=0$. And $\forall\ x\neq x_0, f(x)>0$. I have no idea. Thinking more than two days.

Argue by contradiction, only finitely many discontinuities, then ...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Points of discontinuity of a bijective function $f:\mathbb{R} \to [0,\infty)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8149/points-of-discontinuity-of-a-bijective-function-f-mathbbr-to-0-infty). Some more: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/8149/.